# How do i pass raw HTML from java spring controller to jsp view

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Im just trying something for feasibility purposes.

I am trying to pass raw HTML code in my Spring controller to a specific view. However i want to know if its possible to convert raw html to a string and then pass the HTML string to the view. Theres errors in "String message" because i havented formatted the HTML into a string.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
    public ModelAndView test (ModelMap model) {
        //Map<String, Object> cat = (Map<String, Object>) incidentService.getIncidentCategories();

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("test2.jsp");
        String message = <p><img alt="alt text" src="http://localhost:8080/aston.jpg" style="height:974px; width:2386px" />This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.</p> // 
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);

        return mv;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code has compilation errors. Can you fix them?

Comment: Is the `message` String supposed to be the complete markup you want to return from the controller method, or do you want it to be inserted into more template from another template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i basically come to this solution.
In spring controller, i am passing encoded escaped html to the view.

mv.addObject("Description", HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(eknow.get(0).getDescription()));

unescaped:"

testing 12345

"

escaped:<p>testing 12345</p>

<p><img alt="alt text" src="http://localhost:8080/logo.gif&quot; style="height:303px; width:1191px" /></p>

And then on the view i store the escaped value in a hidden input.

And then i get the element by jquery and reverse the action from escaped to unescaped.

```
var testing = $("#test").val();
alert(decodeURIComponent(testing));
CKEDITOR.instances.description.setData(decodeURIComponent(testing));
```

This will then set and render html raw code for my HTML editor.

If you know of any way to optimize this, please let me know. But this solution works.

Comment: escaped: &lt;p&gt;testing 12345&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;img alt=&quot;alt text&quot; src=&quot;http://localhost:8080/logo.gif&quot; style=&quot;height:303px; width:1191px&quot; /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `@RestController` or `@ResponseBody`, which will not go thru `viewResolver`

```
@RestController 
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public String text1() {
      return "<p>hello world</p>";
    }
}
```

OR

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public @ResponseBody String text2() {
      return "<p>hello world again!</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<div class="well"><c:out value="${message}" escapeXml="false"></c:out></div>`

you also need to escape quotes in ur message 
`String message = "<p><img alt=\"alt text\" src=\"http://localhost:8080/aston.jpg\" style=\"height:974px; width:2386px\" />This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.</p>"`

add the `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>` to your jsp page.

assuming that u r using jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to return HTML from Spring controller.

If you are using latest version of Spring.Use "**produces**" attribute from @RequestMapping

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/testUrl" }, method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
```

if you are using **older** versions of Spring, simple

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.getWriter().println(...) // print your html here
```